# ES6 push and bind to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Please pardon my newbie verbiage here while I attempt to explain my problem (also I did search and came up with nothing, I'd also like to use ES6, not jQuery)

I'm trying to have a text input that when entered it's pushed into an empty array.  When more input is entered in, I would like to have that bound to the array as well.

So I have it working, kinda.  I can get one thing in the array but I can't seem to anything else to go in there.  Here's what I have so far:

My html:

```
<input type="text" class="theplayer pre" name="Player" id="bind" placeholder="Enter Names" onclick='javascript: this.value = ""' />
```

My JS:

```
    let namesOfPlayers = [];
    const currentValue = document.getElementById("bind").value;
    namesOfPlayers.push(currentValue);
    //I don't know how to add in another text/value here
    console.log('namesOfPlayers', namesOfPlayers);
```

I don't know if I'm supposed to be doing a for each here or if there's a way to bind another value into the array.

Thanks and much appreciated for letting me try to clumsily explain this.

Comment: You need to declare a function, and call it from `onclick` (there's also no need for `javascript:`)

Comment: so like this

 `function myArr() {
  const currentValue = document.getElementById("bind").value;
  let namesOfPlayers = [];
  namesOfPlayers.push(currentValue);
  console.log('namesOfPlayers', namesOfPlayers);
}`  

and on html 
<input type="text" class="theplayer pre" name="Player" id="bind" placeholder="Enter Names" onclick='myArr()' />`

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/9rorkpj5/

Comment: @sthig Declaring `nameOfPlayers` array within function would create new array at each `click` event

Comment: try with the onkeypress event, and if you want do something with the array use the .map function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include `<input type="button">` element as sibling of `<input type="text">` element. At `click` on `<input type="button">` `.push()` `.value` of `<input type="text">` to array

```html
<input type="text" 
       class="theplayer pre" 
       name="Player" 
       id="bind" 
       placeholder="Enter Names" />
<input type="button" value="click" />
<script>
  let namesOfPlayers = [];
  let input = document.getElementById("bind");
  let button = input.nextElementSibling;
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    namesOfPlayers.push(input.value);
    console.log(namesOfPlayers);
  });
</script>
```