# Javascript push input into Array causes several arrays not one

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

This is a follow up to my question, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151793/es6-push-and-bind-to-an-array/43151917#43151917)

I am trying to write that when a user enters in their name (string) into the field and hits enter, it pushes it into an array.  It works, kinda.  But I get an error when I try it one and then it produces multiple arrays when I try it another.  I don't want to use jQuery.

Here is the HTML

```
<input type="text"
   class="theplayer pre"
   name="Player"
   id="bind"
   placeholder="Enter Names"
    />
<button type="button" id="thego" class="pre enterteam" value="click">Go</button>
```

Here is my js that works but it creates multiple arrays instead of pushing everything into one array (because the nextElementSibling is not called, I know this, see next block

```
let namesOfPlayers = [];
let currentValue = document.getElementById("bind").value;
let button = currentValue.nextElementSibling;
document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    const key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (key === 13) {
        namesOfPlayers.push(currentValue);
        console.log('namesOfPlayers', namesOfPlayers);
    }
});
```

Here is my js that throws an error (I don't want to use jQuery)

I want that when a user hits enter or clicks the button that the string is submitted and added into the empty array.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to make that work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When does this code run? My guess is that you are binding multiple `keypress` event listeners but you really only want one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fetch the value of the input too soon. You should fetch it only when the button is clicked, not before.

Secondly, the button does not have a `keypress` event, nor a `keyCode` associated with it. You need to listen to the `click` event.

So do this:

```js
let namesOfPlayers = [];
let input = document.getElementById("bind");
let button = input.nextElementSibling;
button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    namesOfPlayers.push(input.value);
    console.log('namesOfPlayers', namesOfPlayers);
});
```

```html
<input type="text"
       class="theplayer pre"
       name="Player"
       id="bind"
       placeholder="Enter Names" />
<button type="button" id="thego" class="pre enterteam" value="click">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, i added a `click` (for the button) and `keypress` (for the text input) events

so if you click enter when you focus on the text `input` the text in the input will be in the array.

and the same will happen if you click "Go" button

```js
 let namesOfPlayers = [];
 let currentElement = document.getElementById("bind");
 let button = currentElement.nextElementSibling;
 let addPlayer = () => {
   namesOfPlayers.push(currentElement.value);
   console.log(namesOfPlayers); // Just for testing
 }
currentElement.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13 || e.keyCode === 13) {
        addPlayer();
    }
});

button.addEventListener('click', addPlayer);
```

```html
   <input type="text"
               class="theplayer pre"
               name="Player"
               id="bind"
               placeholder="Enter Names"
                />
            <button type="button" id="thego" class="pre enterteam" value="click">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

CurrentValue is defined outside of the event listener, so it only gets called once, on initialisation. That's why the push call only injects empty strings. Also, the button doesn't do anything because it doesn't have a listener.

Here's the updated code:

```
let namesOfPlayers = [];
// It's better to get the button by id instead of getting it by a previous child.
// This is because it might cause some unexpected behaviour if someone changed the HTML.
const button = document.getElementById("thego");

button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    addItemToArray(namesOfPlayers);
});

document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
  const key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key === 13) {
    addItemToArray(namesOfPlayers);
  }
});

function addItemToArray(namesOfPlayers) {
  const currentValue = document.getElementById("bind").value;
  namesOfPlayers.push(currentValue);
  console.log('namesOfPlayers', namesOfPlayers);
}
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/4k4a9m6y/

But, you're better off with a form to improve performance.

```js
let namesOfPlayers = [];
const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  const currentValue = document.getElementById("bind").value;
  namesOfPlayers.push(currentValue);
  console.log('namesOfPlayers', namesOfPlayers);
});
```

```html
<form id="form"
      action="javascript:void(0);">
  <input type="text"
         class="theplayer pre"
         name="Player"
         id="bind"
         placeholder="Enter Names"
         />
  <button type="submit" id="thego" class="pre enterteam" value="click">Go</button>
</form>
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/4k4a9m6y/2/